# How can I add a custom resolution to be always available for only a specific monitor using Intel's driver on xorg

Tags: xorg, kde, intel-graphics, kde-neon

I have a super-ultrawide (32:9) monitor from Samsung (G9 Odyssey) and it works fine under windows (with a nvidia gpu), however my work laptop (with hdmi 2) which CAN (sometimes) see the full resolution (5120x1440) will decide half of the time not to.

If I re-run xrandr a few times usually it'll "notice" that there are more resolutions and I can then switch, but sometimes it'll randomly switch back to 1024x768@60.

I saw that it's apparently an issue with how the monitor identifies the resolutions or whatever, so I thought I'd just add a custom xorg resolution to my system, but for obvious reasons I want it to only be available for the hdmi and only for this specific monitor.

I've been trying to get the edid of the monitor and do something with it, but all the time when I tried it said it's corrupted or too long or whatever and that didn't go so well.

How can I create a configuration file for xorg (and maybe also wayland for the future?) so it stays detected?

Using KDE Neon User Edition 5.22 with kernel 5.11.0-22-generic

Running xrandr got me a list of 4 resolutions for hdmi, then nothing (segmentation fault), then a list of multiple resolutions (including the one  I wanted), and looped.

Comment: Hello, this looks like a good question. It might be helpful for contributors if you to post the output of getting the edid, and some of the other commands you've tried. Also - what is the model of the work laptop?

Comment: @DannyStaple I don't have it on right now but all the edid said was that the parsing program crashed. As for xrandr I added some text. For now I ordered a proper hdmi2 cable, as it was brought to my attention I could be using a bad one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is kind of simple and ridiculous.

Don't use HDMI. It's bad. I use a DP <-> USB-C cable and it's perfect.
Apparently the intel driver stuff for HDMI is just bad.